fncychap style not applying to toc when etoc is loaded
I use fncychap to apply a custom style to chapters, including table of contents. However, when etoc package is loaded (which i use for creating local tocs for each chapter), the fncychap style does not apply anymore to \tableofcontents.
Is there a way for fncychap to apply to \tableofcontents even when etoc is loaded?
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,english]{book}
\usepackage[Sonny]{fncychap}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{comment} 
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear,]{biblatex}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{siunits}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\usepackage{etoc} % if disabled, fncychap is applied to \tableofcontents

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents %fncychap Sonny is not applied

\mainmatter
\chapter{This chapter title uses fncychap Sonny}

\backmatter
\listoffigures %fncychap Sonny is applied
\end{document}


Do you need \usepackage[titles]{tocloft}?

Yes, to use the commands \renewcommand\cftfigafterpnum{\vskip0pt\par}
\renewcommand\cfttabafterpnum{\vskip0pt\par} which allow me to keep tables of figures and tables with normal linespacing (i am also using \usepackage{parskip} which unfortunately modify spacing in these tables
But egreg solution works fine even with \usepackage[titles]{tocloft} so i accept it

You need to reset the style. I minimized the example, avoiding packages not needed for it.
However, you should be aware that there is no siunits package; there is SIunits, but it's largely obsolete; on case insensitive file systems calling it siunits might work, but…
Also note that tocloft and etoc fight each other.
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{etoc}
\usepackage[Sonny]{fncychap}

\etocsettocstyle{\chapter*{\contentsname}}{}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents %fncychap Sonny is not applied

\mainmatter
\chapter{This chapter title uses fncychap Sonny}

\backmatter
\listoffigures %fncychap Sonny is applied

\end{document}


Personal comment: possibly Sonny is the least ugly style provided by fncychap. But “ugly” still applies.

Thank you, it works
Would you suggest other packages than fncychap?
